# Multiple cluster titles with highcharts

Tags: javascript, html, charts, highcharts

I am trying to implement a venn diagram for a webpage of mine with highcharts.

I had a look at their example fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/venn-diagram

And found out that you can set different clusters by adding sets to objects:

```
series: [{
        type: 'venn',
        name: 'The Unattainable Triangle',
        data: [{
            sets: ['Good'],
            value: 2
        }, {
            sets: ['Fast'],
            value: 2
        }, {
            sets: ['Cheap'],
            value: 2
        }, {
            sets: ['Good', 'Fast'],
            value: 1,
            name: 'More expensive'
        }, {
            sets: ['Good', 'Cheap'],
            value: 1,
            name: 'Will take time to deliver'
        }, {
            sets: ['Fast', 'Cheap'],
            value: 1,
            name: 'Not the best quality'
        }, {
            sets: ['Fast', 'Cheap', 'Good'],
            value: 1,
            name: 'They\'re dreaming'
        }]
    }]
```

In return you can achieve a venn diagram like this:

[image]

However, I want to be able to set different titles in these clusters. Kind of like this (see additional title):
[image]

Does anyone know if this is at all possible or if there is another library that can do this?

Comment: The only solution which came to my mind is to use the SVGRenderer tool to render those titles as an custom labels. https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#label You can add it dynamically inside the render callback function https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.render

Comment: @SebastianWędzel Hmmm thank you for your approach but I think it's not at all possible to do it that way I want. I would like to be able to click on these titles as well... guess I need to go for a custom javascript implementation in that case.

Comment: You can attach any events to the label created by using the SVGRenderer, take a look: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/L648upcy/

Comment: @SebastianWędzel Oh wow that is cool, thank you! I will play around with it for a bit, maybe I can indeed achieve what I want to :)

Comment: sure! In case of any further help in this case - feel free to ask.